# Apache Site Slow To Load, possibly allowoverride or rewrite issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am finding that my websites are slow to load the first page but is fine after that, some experimenting with apache configuration suggests one of the following maybe the issue:

1. **AllowOverride** - I know having AllowOverride set to All can slow a site down as it looks for .htaccess files in every folder so I moved the configuration into the virtual hosts file and made AllowOverride None thus turning off .htaccess files, this initially seemed to solve the problem but when I tried it again the problem returned so maybe it wasn't that.
2. I removed the AllowOverride line so it defaults back to the default setting for this (none). This seemed to help but again it still occurs at times.
3. It could be the rewrite rules which are:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On              

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+\.)?example\.com/.*$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search?q=cache [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !msn. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yahoo. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]    

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
   ```

However some sites don't use this and in fact don't even use rewrites and are still slow so this doesn't seem to be the problem either.

Any ideas?

**Edited:**

It is not the site that is the issue as even a simple HTML that only has "Hello World" has issues.

It was working fine on previous versions of Apache but since the upgrade to 2.4 (when a lot of things changed especially configuarations) it has become slow.

Comment: "...slow to load the first page but is fine after that..."  You are looking in the wrong place.  Start using Firebug / Pagespeed or equiv to sort out your content caching.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the delay is before you get to the site like some kinda server issue. When the site has loaded it is fast, you can move around no problems. It is even slow to first load with a site that has just "hello world" and nothing else so isn't the content that is the issue.

Comment: Are you hosted on a shared service?

Comment: If its your own server then there's the option of using `strace` to timetime whats going on.  I have a test VM which broadly mirrors my prod stack and I have used strace to good effect to hunt down issues like this.  E.g. [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/search) though I find it easier to start Apache in debugger mode to do this.

Comment: I downgraded to apache 2.2 and it seems to be solved so appears it is a 2.4 issue

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but it would be good to know why A2.4 is killimng yr performance.  Guess we've find out sooner or later :-)

Comment: I agree it would be nice to know but am out of things to test/try in an attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with slow loading of CSS, JS and other static files with Apache and RewriteRule. Check with Chrome's Developer Tools > Network if you have this problem too. In my case the .php was rendering fast but then I had to wait 10 seconds for .css files to load! If this is the same for you, my fix will probably works for you as well. Since you state that the first load is slow and later ones are fast (caching of css files in browser) I guess it will :)

Instead of making the RewriteRule engine handle all static files and actually Rewrite the static filenames as well...:

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css|pdf|eot|woff|ttf|svg|ico)$ /$0 [L]
```

... it's better to not bother the RewriteRule engine handle static filenames at all:

```
RewriteCond $0 !\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css|pdf|eot|woff|ttf|svg|ico|html)$
```

In your case you don't specifically have a RewriteRule for your static files but also no RewriteCond, so I guess alle requests are just passed through to the RewriteRule engine.

By the way, I don't know why it is such a problem loading static files through RewriteRule with Apache (2.4). Anyone?

Hope this helps you as well!